# Problem with medians in triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

It would appear that the segment passing through the centroid and being parallel to one of a triangle's sides is 2/3 the side to which it is parallel. I would be grateful if someone could help me out in comprehending why this is so. I have the feeling that the medians theorem should or might be resorted to in this demonstration, but I cannot find the path. Please do not consider anything trivial. And be as much as explicative as possible.

Comment: "THE triangle"?  *Which* triangle?

Comment: Any triangle. I edited the question. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is due to the classical result that the centroid of a triangle divides each median in two segments, the longest of which is twice the shortest. More precisely, if $M$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ and $AA'$ is a median, then $\overline{AM}=2\overline{MA'}$ and so forth. Now, if $D\in AB$ and $E\in AC$ are such that $ED\parallel BC$ and $M\in ED$, then by similarity of $\triangle ADE$ and $\triangle ABC$ we have $$ED:BC=AD:AB$$ and, by the parallel lines theorem $$AD:AB=AM:AA'=2:3$$

Comment: Absolute thanks for responding so promptly to my request. I have put down your explanation as a paper visualisation. You interestingly mentioned a "parallel lines theorem" dealing with the 2/3 ratio. I am looking into it to have a full comprehension of the problem. This would apparently clarify the matter in a definitive manner.

Comment: Actually, I have never encountered a parallel lines theorem involving or stating a 2:3 ratio. I am trying to associate these two elements: parallelity, and 2:3 ratio.

Comment: It's the theorem about three parallel lines and two transversals. Or, if you prefer, similarity of $\triangle ADM$ and $\triangle ABA'$. $2:3$ is just what $AM:AA'$ is.